# Reason for my character not knowing much about the world

Tags: fantasy-races

My main character and his closest 3 friends are human boys, around 15 years old, who live in a fantasy medieval world.

In this world there are many non human races (that actually live peacefully alongside humans all over the world), but the boys never saw anything but humans so far.

I want to write this story in a way that the characters discover the world at the same time as the reader.

My question is: what are some good reasons for them to not have seen any other races yet?

Bonus info: the main character is from a noble house, if that matters.

Comment: Seems more of a plot then a world building question to be honest.

Comment: I agree this is about a plot. And "good reasons" are a matter of opinion

Comment: I was 19 years old when I first met a black person. I *knew* that black people existed, but that's only because in the modern world we have pervasive general education and mass media; they didn't have those in back then. What they did have in the medieval world was very little mobility; most people never went 20 miles away from the place where they had been born. It may simply be the case that on the estate where the boys live there are no people of the other species. Consider goats and donkeys; they live alongside humans all over the world: but very many people have never been near one.

Comment: Sorry if this is more a plot question than world building. @AlexP very good point. You gave me some ideas, thanks :)

Comment: Historically there have been many nobilities where members of the nobility were 'protected' from dealing with the lower orders of society. For example, Heian Japan. Such social exclusion is a normal feature of such societies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They have read a lot but seen very little.**

[The History of Herodotus](http://classics.mit.edu/Herodotus/history.mb.txt)

> Eastward of these Indians are another tribe, called Padaeans, who are
>   wanderers, and live on raw flesh. This tribe is said to have the
>   following customs:- If one of their number be ill, man or woman, they
>   take the sick person, and if he be a man, the men of his acquaintance
>   proceed to put him to death, because, they say, his flesh would be
>   spoilt for them if he pined and wasted away with sickness. The man
>   protests he is not ill in the least; but his friends will not accept
>   his denial- in spite of all he can say, they kill him, and feast
>   themselves on his body. So also if a woman be sick, the women, who are
>   her friends, take her and do with her exactly the same as the men...
>
> There is another set of Indians whose customs are very different. They
>   refuse to put any live animal to death, they sow no corn, and have no
>   dwelling-houses. Vegetables are their only food.. If one of them is
>   attacked with sickness, he goes forth into the wilderness, and lies
>   down to die; no one has the least concern either for the sick or for
>   the dead.

Herodotus was a classical author.  Apparently he was not much read in medieval times but not lost because we have his writings.   He is excellent and he describes lots of things, events and people in far off lands.  Your boys have a Herodotus equivalent in the library on the Ireland-equivalent island kingdom where they grew up.  They have read it many times.  It is exciting, gory, racy and altogether excellent.  It is not totally inaccurate.

Your boys not only do not know much, but they think they do.  Each of your chapters can be prefaced by an excerpt from that classic text relevant to the story that is to come, or not.  Rather than being complete ignoramuses, your boys come to the greater world with a skewed and not entirely wrong world view.  That will be more fun to write and maybe more realistic if they are semi-educated nobility.

Comment: The *Histories* of Herodotus were first printed in 1474 (in Lorenzo Valla's Latin translation). The [edition of 1537](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_BDm_darB0y0C) is available at Archive.org.

Comment: Great answer. Specially the suggestion to begin each chapter with a piece from a book they've read about the world. Thanks!